# PreferenceScreen has been deprecated by API 29

Tags: android

I did create preferences XML then I see the `PreferenceScreen` has been deprecated by API 29. What is the replacement?

And you can see depreciation message here:

[image]

Answer (score 61, accepted):

It's deprecated in API level 29 base on [Google Document](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/Preference) and also by the Google recommendation you should use [AndroidX Preference Library](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/preference/package-summary.html) instead.

You can check AndroidX Preference guide in this [link](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/settings.html)

If you still have the problem after `Migrate to Androidx` you can use

```
<androidx.preference.PreferenceScreen
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

</androidx.preference.PreferenceScreen>
```

instead of

```
<PreferenceScreen
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">


</PreferenceScreen>
```

It's not necessary but you can add this implementation into your Gradle too.

```
implementation 'androidx.preference:preference:X.Y.Z'
```

Comment: If you add `implementation 'androidx.preference:preference:X.Y.Z'`(change version number accordingly) to Gradle you can save adding `androidx.preference.` prefix to XML preferences file.

Answer (score 3):

As described in the [official doc](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/PreferenceScreen):

> **This class was deprecated in API level 29.**
>   Use the [AndroidX](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx.html) [Preference Library](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/preference/package-summary.html) for consistent behavior across all devices

Comment: And now there no type hints :/

Answer (score 1):

This class was deprecated in API level `29`.
Use the `AndroidX Preference Library` for consistent behavior across all devices.

Add to `build.gradle`:

`implementation "androidx.preference:preference-ktx:1.2.0"`

This way you can use it easily:

`private val preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context)`