# Why is android.preference.PreferenceManager deprecated in API level 29?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, sharedpreferences

I know we can use `androidx.preference.PreferenceManager`. But what was the problem with the existing one?

Comment: I could as well ask: why you even care? `PreferenceDataStore` addresses some of the problems.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57443578/4921704